# How to center pagination block with react-bootstrap

Tags: html, reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap

I have built out a custom pagination setup for a small web-app I am building using `react-bootstrap`. I have got all the integration and pagination to work correctly. I am relatively new to `react` / `bootstrap` & have NOT done a lot of `css`. I want to avoid `css` to the extent possible, which is why I chose to work with `react-bootstrap`

The issue I am having is with not being able to make my pagination appear in the center of the  block:
[image]

My react hook looks like this:

```
return (
        <div>
            <div align="center">
                <div className="p-3">
                    <Disclaimer/>
                </div>
                <Pagination size="lg" class="text-center">
                    {pages}
                </Pagination>
                {custom_cards}
                <Pagination size="lg" class="text-center">
                    {pages}
                </Pagination>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

I know the fix is here:

```
                <Pagination size="lg" class="text-center">
                    {pages}
                </Pagination>
```

I have tried `align` and other things like `text-center`. Being new, I don't have the right keywords to power a good search result for me on web. If you have any leads here I would appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bootstrap classes to center the pagination component

```
<Pagination size="lg" className="d-flex justify-content-center">
    {pages}
</Pagination>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add these two CSS properties to a parent div:

style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
  <Pagination>
    <Pagination.First />
    <Pagination.Prev />
    <Pagination.Item>{1}</Pagination.Item>
    <Pagination.Ellipsis />

    <Pagination.Item>{10}</Pagination.Item>
    <Pagination.Item>{11}</Pagination.Item>
    <Pagination.Item active>{12}</Pagination.Item>
    <Pagination.Item>{13}</Pagination.Item>
    <Pagination.Item disabled>{14}</Pagination.Item>

    <Pagination.Ellipsis />
    <Pagination.Item>{20}</Pagination.Item>
    <Pagination.Next />
    <Pagination.Last />
  </Pagination>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use a footer/pagination class and .css class.

```
.Pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

<footer className="Pagination">
   <p>I'm a footer</p>
</footer>
```